# crystal reports can it use a stored procedure

Tags: ibm-midrange, crystal-reports-xi, db2-400

HI I have a task to improve the time taking to load and run a CR. it is over 30 minutes. It is going against DB2 server and all the processing is being done in the Crystal. So my first thought is to make a view on the server which will then be much faster. However the report has a from and to date.

SO then, I would need a Stored procedure. but that means, i need to pass the dates from the CR to the SP on the server.

I have not seen this done but perhaps there are techniques to do this? If not i will try a view but there is mass amt of data on some of these tables.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the best performance if you push as much of the processing as possible to the host.

First, try an SQL view on the host without a WHERE clause.  In your SQL query referencing the view in Crystal Reports, add your WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.  The system will merge your client side SQL with the SQL in the host view, and deliver the net effect of the merged SQL. I do not believe you need a stored procedure, and using a view is easier and more flexible.

I used the below technique once to squeeze some extra performance out of a complicated SQL view, but it gets a bit involved and therefore I wouldn't use it if the technique above wasn't yielding the desired performance after optimization efforts.

An alternate way is to use an SQL view by using a TABLE user defined function to feed the report parameters to the view, where the TABLE function gets the parameters from a temporary table.

Example:

```
declare global temporary table SESSION.MY_PARMS (FROM_DATE, TO_DATE) as ( 
  values ( CURRENT_DATE - 30 days, CURRENT_DATE ) 
) with data with replace
;

create or replace function MY_SCHEMA.MY_PARMS_UDF( )

  returns table ( FROM_DATE date, TO_DATE date )

  language sql
  specific MY_SCHEMA.MY_PARMS_F
  not deterministic
  disallow parallel
  no external action
  reads SQL data
  called on null input
  not fenced

  set option dbgview   = *source
            ,commit    = *nc
            ,closqlcsr = *endmod
            ,datfmt    = *iso
            ,dftrdbcol = *none
            ,tgtrls    = V7R1M0

return

select FROM_DATE, TO_DATE from SESSION.MY_PARMS
;

create or replace view MY_SCHEMA.MY_REPORT_VIEW for system name MY_REPORTV as (

   select     *
   from       table( MY_PARMS_UDF( ) )
                as MY_PARMS ( FROM_DATE, TO_DATE )
   inner join MY_REPORT_DATA  R
         on   R.MY_REPORT_DATE >= MY_PARMS.FROM_DATE
         and  R.MY_REPORT_DATE <= MY_PARMS.TO_DATE
)
;
```

In Crystal Reports, you'll need to create parameter table SESSION.MY_PARMS per each job (or refresh its contents using UPDATE if you've already created it in the report job and you prefer an UPDATE). I haven't used Crystal Reports since 2002 so I can't efficiently help out with how to do that part.

Then, in Crystal reports you'll be able embed a query like this below that effectively uses the report parameters you pushed into table SESSION.MY_PARMS.

```
select * from MY_SCHEMA.MY_REPORT_VIEW
;
```

Because table MY_PARMS is a SESSION temporary table in library / schema QTEMP, this design supports multiple users running the report at the same time using different parameters (because each user will have a separate JOB and separate QTEMP library).

The system will late bind to table SESSION.MY_PARMS inside table UDF MY_PARMS_UDF, meaning you can even delete and recreate that table, and the next reference to the VIEW and UDF will pick up the new copy of table SESSION.MY_PARMS (or newly updated row if you simply UPDATE the row in SESSION.MY_PARMS).

I think there is a good chance that you could use an SQL Stored Procedure that accepts your report parameters as input and returns one or more result sets back to Crystal Reports for the report.  However, since I haven't used Crystal Reports in so long I don't recall if it supports a CALL to an SQL Stored Procedure. If Crystal Reports supports calling an SQL Stored Procedure with parameters, and receiving one or more result sets from the procedure, that is a bit simpler.  If you do that make sure you use result set oriented SQL in the procedure to build your result set(s), instead of single row cursor processing, in order to maximize performance.

Note that using a procedure is simpler than the UDF and View technique, but a procedure is less flexible, because a procedure must be invoked using a CALL, whereas a VIEW can be referenced anywhere a table can by referenced in a query.  For reasons of flexibility, I rarely use SQL procedures, and instead use VIEWS and UDFs. I also recommend using TABLE UDFs in most cases instead of SCALAR UDFs, because they can be referenced in more places in a query, and make it easier to include their column content in a query result set.

Answer (score 0):

Don't send the parameters through sp, pass the parameters through your code and then get it via DB. check this out it will be helpful..
[MSDN SP Paramerters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)